# Hibernate. Associate two tables with one by one key column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations

I have legacy database with 3 tables: ENTITY1, ENTITY2, PROPERTY. Each entity have several properties. Both entity tables bounded with property-table by entity_id key which is located in property table. So I haven't real constraints.

DB scheme:

[image]

I prefer to store all properties in Map in Entity1-class so I must have many-to-one assotiation in Property-class (I haven't founded other solutions. **Are they exist?**).

**So how can I associate Entity2-class with property-class?**

Enity1.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY1")
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "some_field")
    private String field;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityId")
    @MapKey(name="key")
    private Map<Long, Property> properties;
}
```

Property.class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PROPERTY")
    public class Property {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "property_id")
        private long id;

        @Column
        private long key;

        @Column
        private String value;

//are there other solutions?
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID")
        private Entity1 entity1;
    }
```

Entity2.class skeleton

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY1")
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "some_field")
    private String field;

    // What can I do?
    private Map<Long, Property> properties;
}
```

Can't remove @ManuToOne annoutation from Property.class couse of next exception:

```
11:38:40,825 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."sudir-gateway-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sudir-gateway-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear#primary": java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1460) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:864) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:779) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:107) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
       ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ManyToOne. You just need to specify the JoinColumn annotation on the OneToMany association:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
private Map<Long, Property> properties;
```

AFAIK, doing the same thing on the second entity should work fine. I guess that you're aware that this design will fall apart as soon as an Enity1 has the same ID as an Entity2.

Comment: It's imposible to use both @OneToMany and mappedBy:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: ru.sbt.snuil.model.db.Organization.params`

Comment: If I remove @ManyToOne from Property-bean I have following exception on deploy:

`11:38:40,825 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."sudir-gateway-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sudir-gateway-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear#primary": java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Sorry, the mappedBy shouldn't be there. Your NullPointerException is not debuggable without a complete stack trace.

Comment: Added stacktrace into question body